# Upper bound on KL divergence

Tags: optimization, kullback-leibler, bounds, extreme-value, cross-entropy

Is there a maximum (unique?) to the KL divergence between **discrete** distributions p & q, *with the restriction* that q is a proper probability distribution?

I know KL is unbounded from above when q is unrestricted, but what about when it sums to one?

Comment: AFAIK the definition of KL divergence assumes that $q$ is a proper probability distribution, so I don't think you are adding a meaningful restriction.