# KL divergence between which distributions could be infinity

Tags: probability, distributions, information-theory, kullback-leibler, integral

I know that KL divergence measures difference between two probability distributions. My doubt is for which of the distributions it could become Infinity, putting it in another way, `P(x)` has to produce the values that `Q(x)` cannot.

Or `Q(x)` has to be `0` where `P(x)` does not, because KL divergence is given as below:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\{\log\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\}P(x)dx$$

Can any one tell me by choosing which probability distributions for P(x) and Q(x) we can achieve KL divergence as Infinity.

I think choosing P(x) as uniform distribution and Q(x) as Gaussian distribution could give Infinity, am I right?

Answer (score 14):

What happens to $D_{KL}(p \parallel q)$ when $p(x)$ and/or $q(x)$ is zero? In a strict sense, the log of zero is undefined because there's no value of $x$ such that $e^x = 0$. But, the definition of KL divergence uses the following conventions (see Cover and Thomas, *Elements of Information Theory*):

$$0 \log \frac{0}{0} = 0, \quad
0 \log \frac{0}{q(x)} = 0, \quad
p(x) \log \frac{p(x)}{0} = \infty$$

This implies that KL divergence is infinite if there exists an $x$ where $p(x) > 0$ and $q(x) = 0$. Conversely, $p(x)$ being zero doesn't produce infinity, whether or not $q(x)$ is also zero. Another way of saying this is that KL divergence is finite only if the support of $p$ is contained within the support of $q$. However, note that KL divergence can be infinite *even if* $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are nonzero for all $x$ (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/351947/whats-the-maximum-value-of-kullback-leibler-kl-divergence/352008#352008) for an example).

Regarding your example, this means that KL divergence will be infinite if $p$ is Gaussian and $q$ is uniform, but not the other way around.

Comment: You said "KL divergence is finite **only if** the support of $p$ is contained within the support of $q$". Why did you use the word only? If by "contained within" you mean $\subset$ then there is an obvious case $p \equiv q$ (then support(p)=support(q)) when KL=0 (finite). And If by "contained within" you mean $\subseteq$ then your claim is false (see your own hyperlink above).

Comment: @Rodvi Please note the answer states "only if" (which is correct here), not "if and only if" (which would be incorrect). To unpack the statement: If $\operatorname{support}(p) \nsubseteq \operatorname{support}(q)$ then $D_{KL}(p \parallel q) = \infty$. Otherwise, if $\operatorname{support}(p) \subseteq \operatorname{support}(q)$, then $D_{KL}(p \parallel q)$ could be finite *or* infinite.