# KL divergence for disjoint distributions

Tags: kullback-leibler, divergence

According to the article [here](https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2017-08-20-gan/), we have two disjoint distributions as shown below.
[image].

KL divergence for the distributions are

[image]

I don't understand why denominators are 0 for both.

Comment: See the answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362860/kl-divergence-between-which-distributions-could-be-infinity